# Do Indian passport holder with indefinite leave in UK need a transit visa in Dublin?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, dublin

I am an Indian passport holder and indefinite leave in UK.

I have booked Qatar airlines from BHX to India via Dublin and Doha.

First flight is from BHX to Dublin at 21:35 reaching Dublin at 22:45.(Operated by Aer Lingus)

After a layover of 9.5 hours, connecting flight to Doha at 08:40 next morning. Do I need a transit visa for this in Dublin ?

Note : I dont have any plans to enter Dublin.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here are the requirements for TVOW

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Passengers transiting through Dublin (DUB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country. They must:
>
> - arrive at and depart from Terminal 2, and
> - be transiting between 04:00 and 16:00 on the same calendar day, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

Source: [Timatic via Emirates.com](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&AC=GB&AV=United%20Kingdom&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=IE&TV=Ireland&h=7c39a14fdd502249d3429a6f98bd52d012555e0)

Unfortunately your flight to Dublin falls out of those hours and the two flights are not on the same calendar day, hence you **can not not transit without a visa on this itinerary.** If you can reschedule your flights so they fall within the time range and terminal limits given above, you won't need a visa to enter Ireland.

Comment: Why the "might not" wording? The OP will have to leave Terminal 2 after arrival in DUB, and that requires passing through Irish Immigration. I think a better answer would be "You cannot make this overnight transfer unless you have a visa to enter Ireland."

Comment: @David updated.

Comment: Excellent. I added two qualifications to the last sentence as well.

Comment: Do flights from the UK arrive in the international area of the airport?

Comment: @phoog, sorry, I don't really know

Comment: Thanks @david . All this happened evening. the flight was booked though QatarAirways ( through Budget Air vendor) . I even had the online check-in complete. Once I was in airport for bag drop, I was not allowed to continue. This was a first time I had such a transit and I had to rebook by paying a lot.

Comment: @phoog There is no domestic arrivals at Dublin; even domestic passengers clear immigration (with an Irish greeting+boarding pass+possibly DL being sufficient for locals)